DAX filter measure based on multiple critera
I have a large dataset with many rows. I want to be able to filter the  power bi table visual as provided below based on multiple criteria using measure added to a parameter with slicer.
One filter selection is to be able to see orders not delivered AND days from order date is already greater than 3 days.



Order ID
Country
Order Date
Packed Date
Delivered Date
Days from Order




A1111
SG
2024-11-01
2024-11-03
2024-11-04
7


B2222
MY
2024-11-02
2024-11-04
2024-11-05
6


C3333
IN
2024-11-03
2024-11-05

5


D4444
ID
2024-11-04
2024-11-06
2024-11-07
4


E5555
HK
2024-10-31
2024-11-02

8


F6666
VN
2024-11-01
2024-11-03
2024-11-04
7


G7777
SG
2024-11-03
2024-11-05
2024-11-06
5


H8888
MY
2024-11-04


4



I manage to filter the blank rows for  Delivered date with this DAX measure:
No delivered date = 
CONCATENATEX (
    FILTER (
        'dataset',
        ISBLANK('dataset'[Delivered Date])
    ),
   'dataset'[Delivered Date]),
    ", "
)

If I add another criteria (days from Order Date > 3) to filter based on multiple criteria, it does not work.
CONCATENATEX (
    FILTER (
        'dataset',
         ISBLANK('dataset'[Delivered Date]) &&
    'dataset'[Order Date]) + 3 > TODAY()
    ),
   'dataset'[Delivered Date]),
    ", "
)

Would appreciate any advice on how to use DAX measure to filter based on multiple criteria.

I would go for creating a calculated column to use it as a filter on your table visual with the value of 1 :
OverdueOrdersFlag = 
IF(
    ISBLANK('dataset'[Delivered Date]) && 
    DATEDIFF('dataset'[Order Date], TODAY(), DAY) > 3,
    1, 
    0
)


If you want to use a measure (which I don't recommend here) :
NoDeliveredAndOverdueOrders =
CONCATENATEX (
    FILTER (
        'dataset',
        ISBLANK('dataset'[Delivered Date]) &&
        DATEDIFF('dataset'[Order Date], TODAY(), DAY) > 3
    ),
    'dataset'[Order ID],
    ", "
)


